# Docker's JSON log driver doesn't log container name/allow to add extra fields

Tags: logging, docker-compose

I'm trying add extra fields to the Docker container JSON logs. I've read through [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/logging/overview/) page on configuring logging drivers, but JSON portion of the documentation doesn't allow any tagging or allowing to turn on extra fields.

For context, I have a container for my database, webapp, and ELK stack. I have a filebeat containers reading logs from the Docker container logs located at /var/lib/docker/containers/. Filebeat then sends it to the ELK stack.

Things I've tried/considered:

- Since container ID's change dynamically, hard coding it is not an option.
- As far as I know, there isn't a place to hard code container or service names.
- I've considered using the other logging drivers available, including fluentd, but they are not a viable option. If Filebeat is down, then the everything else goes down.

As of now I'm just fiddling with the log driver label options to see if that does anything.

Comment: I think the link that you posted has a section above the JSON portion that shows how you can add attributes from the command-line when invoking `docker daemon`.. it uses the `-e option`.. have you tried this?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm doing this through docker-compose. So I type everything out in my docker-compose.yml then do a `docker-compose up -d`. It seems the  -e is to set environment variables. I do have environment variables set on one of my containers, but it doesn't show up in the logs either.

Comment: If you found a solution to this problem please share it with the world :)

Comment: I've given up on pursuing this method :(

Comment: I wound up using GELF as logging driver because it delivers a lot of usefull fields. Then I deliver logs with UDP to logstash (in swarm) and filter log message to contain additional fields

Answer (score 1):

To add additional fields to the logging output with docker-compose do the following in docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    image: hello-world/web:latest
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        labels: "production_status"
        env: "os"
    labels:
      production_status: "testing"
    environment:
      - os=ubuntu
```

You need to specify the labels/env that should display in the logs, and set the corresponding label/env on the service

Answer (score -1):

@smythie That didn't do anything to actually change the name of the log files themselves. They still sit at `container-id-json.log`.

Comment: It is preferred to write this in comment section.